# Fetching all tags to make a navigation component, Ghost

Tags: handlebars.js, ghost-blog

I was creating a ghost blog and i created a custom component to display all the tags in the blog.

I used the below code to do so,

```
{{#get "tags" limit="all"}}
    <ul class="tags">
        {{#foreach tags}}
            <li>
                <a href="{{url}}">{{name}}</a>
            </li>
        {{/foreach}}
    </ul>
{{/get}}
```

I made the component to act as a filter. But I am facing some issues,

1. Tags with no posts are not displaying.
2. Also is there any way to know which tag filter is currently active?

can someone help me with what I am doing wrong.?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe tags with no posts technically don't exist so they don't they don't create empty page routes, as all tags have their own tag page (`/tag/example-tag/`). As for knowing the active class I assume you're wanting to apply an active class to the tag link, which can be done with `link_class`:

```html
<a class="tag {{link_class for=url class='tag-current'}}" href="{{url}}">{{name}}</a>
```

Comment: but when I do so, I'm getting `tag-current` for all my `<a>` tags. this is my code,    `<a class={{link_class for=url class='tag-current'}} href="{{url}}">{{name}}</a>`  am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: This might be because you're putting it inside the page context, `{{#tag}}...{{/tag}}`. Try putting it outside of this section and see if the issue persists